# Стек технологий для современных реалтайм онлайн игр с множеством игроков

Tags: node.js, разработка-игр

Подскажите пожалуйста стек технологий для подобных реалтайм игр.

Как игра выдерживается до 200 активных подключений на одном кластере?

Не уж то это node.js так хорошо держит?

Есть подозрение, что front-end websocket+js и back-end всё таки C++.

[image: демо игры]

Comment: Даже один инстанс node.js может сотни CCU держать. А если поднять несколько (по одному на ядро) и раскидывать запросы с помощью nginx, то и тысячи в лёгкую. Само по себе подключение не нагружает сервис (только память жрёт). Если данные отправляются не каждый кадр, то легко потянет.

Comment: @Suvitruf, не в активном реалтайм же, а в пассивном подключении. Там столько всего просчитывается, даже движение пуль.

Comment: И? Чем в этом плане node.js отличается от других языков?

Answer (score 1):

Даже один инстанс node.js может сотни CCU держать.
А если поднять несколько (по одному на ядро) и раскидывать запросы с помощью nginx, то и тысячи в лёгкую.

Само по себе подключение не нагружает сервис (только память отъедает). Если данные отправляются не каждый кадр, то легко потянет.

Другое дело, если там физику нужно обсчитывать. Но, как по мне, если это 2d игра, то потянет. Иначе бы не появлялись штуки вроде [Lance](https://github.com/lance-gg/lance).